# Как удалить дубли из таблицы и обновить внешние ключи связанных таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы posts, tags и pivot-таблица post_tag для связи многие ко многим.
В таблице tags поле name не было сделано уникальным и юзеры добавили множество неуникальных тегов.
Как удалить все дубликаты из tags и автоматически обновить post_tag таким образом, чтобы внешние ключи удаленных тегов стали внешними ключами тех тегов, что остались после удаления и соответствуют им по полю name?

Таблица tags:
id|name

Таблица posts:
id|title|text

Таблица post_tag:
post_id|tag_id

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Сначала обновить. Потом удалить. Потом создать уник4альный индекс.

Comment: обновить на какое нить минимальное значение id если что. update-join-(min/group by), потом delete с самоджойном где больше

Comment: Как определяется уникальность/неуникальность тега?

Comment: уникальность тега определяется по полю name